# Gitlab: Print custom warning

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wonder if it's possible to show a custom warning next to a Gitlab-CI job.

For example, I'd like *in a single job* to lint and style check a terraform configuration, print a warning if it doesn't pass, then create a terraform plan and stop the pipeline if that fails.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `allow_failure` (or set custom `exit_codes`) and exit with listed `exit_codes`. This will show a warning icon without blocking the pipeline.

```
test_job_2:
  script:
    - echo "Run a script that results in exit code 137. This job is allowed to fail."
    - exit 137
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes:
      - 137
      - 255
```

Ref: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

Comment: Is it possible to associate a custom message to the exit code?

Comment: In theory, yes. That requires making a script to exit when such message captured.